# How to convert jdbc template query result to JSON Array in java?

Tags: sql-server, spring, mssql-jdbc

I am converting software from Delphi to Spring boot. I have lots of queries in an existing SQL Server database, and I want to display them.

For every query, I have to create entity class, that override row mapper and create entity class.

```
public class PregledTroskova {
int RbrStavke;
int RbrNaloga;
String Konto;
String SifKomint;
float Duguje;
float Potrazuje;

public PregledTroskova() {
}

public int getRbrStavke() {
    return RbrStavke;
}

public void setRbrStavke(int rbrStavke) {
    RbrStavke = rbrStavke;
}

public int getRbrNaloga() {
    return RbrNaloga;
}

public void setRbrNaloga(int rbrNaloga) {
    RbrNaloga = rbrNaloga;
}

public String getKonto() {
    return Konto;
}

public void setKonto(String konto) {
    Konto = konto;
}

public String getSifKomint() {
    return SifKomint;
}

public void setSifKomint(String sifKomint) {
    SifKomint = sifKomint;
}

public float getDuguje() {
    return Duguje;
}

public void setDuguje(float duguje) {
    Duguje = duguje;
}

public float getPotrazuje() {
    return Potrazuje;
}

public void setPotrazuje(float potrazuje) {
    Potrazuje = potrazuje;
}
}
```

Then after that I have to write one more class for mapper

```
class PregledTroskovaRowMapper implements RowMapper<PregledTroskova> {
@Override
public PregledTroskova mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
    PregledTroskova pregledTroskova = new PregledTroskova();
    pregledTroskova.setDuguje(resultSet.getFloat("Duguje"));
    pregledTroskova.setPotrazuje(resultSet.getFloat("Potrazuje"));
    pregledTroskova.setRbrStavke(resultSet.getInt("RbrStavke"));
    pregledTroskova.setRbrNaloga(resultSet.getInt("RbrNaloga"));
    pregledTroskova.setKonto(resultSet.getString("Konto"));
    pregledTroskova.setSifKomint(resultSet.getString("SifKomint"));
    return pregledTroskova;
}
}
```

Is there any way to just generate json list/array of object where property is result set name value for all rows from select?

Comment: Assuming you are using @RestController, why don't you send List<Object> to client ? Here object is referred as RowMapper entity.

Comment: @abhi3232 but how to fetch values and put assign them to object?

Comment: are you using Hibernate with spring boot?

Comment: That means instead of creating DTOs for every table you want directly return all column value mappings ? Is my understanding correct ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create  an entity class for every query, you can return a `List<Map<String, Object>>` which is a list of all rows, each row is represented by a `Map` (column / value).

Example :

```
final List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(yourQuery);
for (final Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
    // do something like : row.get("yourField");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example :

```
 String sql = "select * from mytable";
   result=  jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new AnyObjectMapper());
```

Mapper (generic) :

```
class AnyObjectMapper implements RowMapper<Map<String, Object>> {

    public AnyObjectMapper() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        ResultSetMetaData rsMeta = rs.getMetaData();
        int colCount = rsMeta.getColumnCount();

        Map<String, Object> columns = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {

            columns.put(rsMeta.getColumnLabel(i), rs.getObject(i));
        }
        return columns;

    }
}
```